# Why can a self-adjoint compact operator on a Hilbert space be approximated by the linear combination of rank 1 operators?

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, orthonormal, compact-operators, self-adjoint-operators

Hilbert-Schmidt Theorem says that suppose $A$ is a self-adjoint compact operator on the Hilbert space $X$, then $X$ has an orthonormal basis $\{e_i \,|\, i \in I\}$ ($I$ is the index set) which is composed of the eigenvectors of $A$. Therefore, for any $x \in X$, we have
\begin{gather}
x=\sum_{i \in I} (x,e_i) e_i, \quad \quad (1) \\
Ax=\sum_{i \in I} \lambda_i (x,e_i) e_i, \quad \quad (2)
\end{gather}
where $\lambda_i$ is the eigenvalue corresponding to $e_i$ ($\lambda_i$ may equal $\lambda_j$ even if $i \neq j$, and the set of eigenvalues of $A$ is countable even if $\{e_i\}$ is not). Through Bessel's inequality, there are countable $(x,e_i)$ not equal to $0$, thus the summations above are actually over countable sets. Then it is said in the textbook that if we list the eigenvalues of $A$ as follows:
\begin{equation}
|\lambda_1| \geq |\lambda_2| \geq \cdots, \quad \quad (3)
\end{equation}
then according to Hilbert-Schmidt Theorem, for any $x \in X$, we have
\begin{equation}
\left\|\left(A-\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i e_i \otimes e_i\right)(x)\right\| = \left\|Ax-\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i (x,e_i) e_i\right\| = \left\|\sum_{i=1}^\infty \lambda_i (x,e_i) e_i\right\| = \left(\sum_{i=n+1}^\infty \lambda_i^2 |(x,e_i)|^2\right)^{1/2} \leq |\lambda_{n+1}| \left(\sum_{i=n+1}^\infty |(x,e_i)|^2\right)^{1/2} \leq |\lambda_{n+1}| \|x\|, \quad \quad (4)
\end{equation}
where $e_i \otimes e_i: X \to X; \ x \mapsto (x,e_i) e_i$ is the rank $1$ operator, therefore we have
\begin{equation}
\left\|A-\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i e_i \otimes e_i\right\| \leq |\lambda_{n+1}| \to 0 \quad (n \to \infty), \quad \quad (5)
\end{equation}
that is,
\begin{equation}
A=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \lambda_i e_i \otimes e_i, \quad \quad (6)
\end{equation}
which implies that a self-adjoint compact operator on a Hilbert space can be approximated by the linear combination of rank $1$ operators.

So here comes the question, when $\{e_i\}$ is uncountable, although there are countable $(x,e_i)$ not equal to $0$, it seems that which of them are not equal to $0$ depends on $x$, and accordingly, the addends in the summation $\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i e_i \otimes e_i$ in (4) actually vary with $x$, so why can we still derive (5) from (4)?

Comment: Even more is true: Every compact operator can be approximated by a linear combination of rank one projections. The argument more or less goes as follows: a compact operator (on a Hilbert space!) can be approximated by a finite-rank operator. Hence, it suffices to show that we can write a finite-rank operator as a linear combination of rank one operators. Since every finite-rank operator decomposed as a linear combination of finite rank positive operators, we may assume that we work with a positive operator $u$. Take an orthonormal basis $\{e_i\}_i$ for the image of $u$ and note that [....]

Comment: [...] we can write $u = \sum_i T_{x_i, x_i}$ where $T_{x_i, x_i}(z) = \langle z, x_i\rangle x_i$ and where $x_i = u^{1/2}(e_i)$. The full argument can be found in Murphy's text, $C^*$-algebras and operator theory, theorem 2.4.6.

Comment: @QuantumSpace Thank you very much! But what confuses me is why we can derive (5) from (4), which appears in several textbooks. I think there must be something I haven't understood. Perhaps by referring to Murphy's book you mentioned, I can manage to make sense of it. Thank you 

Comment: I don't understand where your confusion lies. Neither the $e_i$'s nor the $\lambda_i$'s depend on $x$, so going from $(4)$ to $(5)$ is simply applying the definition of operator norm. Can you maybe clarify your confusion?

Comment: In other words, $\sum_i \lambda_i (e_i \otimes e_i)$ does not depend on any choice of $x$. We can evaluate this operator in $x$ though.

Comment: @QuantumSpace Certainly $\{e_i\}_{i \in I}$ and $\{\lambda_i\}_{i \in I}$ do not depend on $x$. Here is what I want to express: For $x_1,x_2 \in X$, we have $x_1=\sum_{i \in I} (x_1,e_i) e_i$, $x_2=\sum_{i \in I} (x_2,e_i) e_i$. Denote $I_1=\{i \in I | (x_1,e_i) \neq 0\}$, $I_2=\{i \in I | (x_2,e_i) \neq 0\}$. Then $I_1$ and $I_2$ might be different if $x_1 \neq x_2$.

Comment: $\sum_{i \in I} \lambda_i (e_i \otimes e_i) x_1=\sum_{i \in I_1} \lambda_i (e_i \otimes e_i) x_1$, $\sum_{i \in I} \lambda_i (e_i \otimes e_i) x_2=\sum_{i \in I_2} \lambda_i (e_i \otimes e_i) x_2$. So for $x_1$, the summation $\sum_{i \in I} \lambda_i (e_i \otimes e_i)$ becomes $\sum_{i \in I_1} \lambda_i (e_i \otimes e_i)$, and for $x_2$, the summation $\sum_{i \in I} \lambda_i (e_i \otimes e_i)$ becomes $\sum_{i \in I_2} \lambda_i (e_i \otimes e_i)$. That's what I mean by saying the addends in the summation $\sum_{i \in I} \lambda_i (e_i \otimes e_i)$ depends on $x$.

Comment: This does matter because $I$ might be uncountable, and when we write down $\sum_{i=1}^\infty$, we are referring to a countable summation, that is, we are summing over a countable subset of $I$. For $x_1$, the countable subset is $I_1$, and for $x_2$, the countable subset is $I_2$. If instead, we use the notation $\sum_{i \in I}$ through to the end, then there is no such a question, but in doing so, there is no way to say "approximate" (which is always concerned with a sequence).

Comment: I guess that might be the reason why in Brezis's text, _Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations_, Theorem 6.11, $X$ is required to be separable, so that $X$ has a countable orthonormal basis. But it looks like in some other textbooks there is no such requirement.

Comment: There is a notion of unordered sum that is relevant here. The sum $\sum_{i\in I}x_i$ in a normed space is said to be equal to $x$ if the net $\{\sum_{i\in F} x_i\}$ converges to $x$ where $F$ ranges over finite subsets of $I$. This agrees with your interpretation of sum.

Comment: In this way you can talk about the sum without worrying on which subset of $I$ the Fourier coefficients are supported.

Comment: @QuantumSpace Thank you very much 

Comment: Oh, actually $\sum_{i \in I} \lambda_i (e_i \otimes e_i)$ is always a countable summation, as the part that makes $\{e_i\}_{i \in I}$ uncountable can only be those eigenvectors that correspond to the eigenvalue $0$, and $0 (e_i \otimes e_i)=0$. :-P

Answer (score 1):

The addends in the summation $\sum_i \lambda_i (e_i \otimes e_i)$ do not depend on $x$. Indeed, $\{e_i\}_{i \in I}$ and $\{\lambda_i\}_{i \in I}$ were introduced before we even spoke about a fixed element $x \in X$. Hence, as an abstract element, the operator $\sum_i \lambda_i (e_i \otimes e_i)$ does not depend on $x$ in any way.

Therefore, $(5)$ follows from $(4)$ by definition of the operator norm. More generally, the proof uses that if $T: X \to X$ is a linear map with $\|Tx\| \le M\|x\|$ for all $x \in X$, then $\|T\| \le M$. Here,
$$T= \sum_i \lambda_i (e_i \otimes e_i).$$
Hopefully this clears your confusion.